# The ways to attach object to other object in certain places

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Good day. I want to attach "teeth" (sorry, I don't know the right term in english) to my building in certain places - on the top and in outer side so it will looks like that:
[image]
For now i did it with some arrays and duplicates but it work only with primitive shapes - for complicated forms I'll need too much duplicates (there are 8 duplicates on the picture). I thought about the ways how to did this and I suppose I can use particle system with vertex groups or extruding from additional geometry. Maybe geometry nodes but it's too complicated for me. So my question: is there a more native/easy way to achive it? I'm thinking about shrinkwrap modifier but I don't have much experience with it so I don't know how to use it properly. Any advices with direction?

Comment: to be honest: this is a "typical" use case for geometry nodes. I would try to learn it - there are hundreds of free tutorials on yt - and also beginner friendly. I would invest the time to learn it - because it opens new horizons.

Comment: @Chris I agree with you with your "it opens new horizons", but I think you're underestimate power of basic modifiers... I saw unbelivable things people achive with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. One approach is to use a curve together with an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier added to a cube**.

- add a *Path* to the scene which creates a *Nurbspath* object. To get sharp path corners you need to select one control point in *Edit* mode, and choose the menu entry *Curve > Set Spline Type > Poly* to get a poly curve.
- on the *Object Data Properties* tab, in section *Active Spline* tick the *Cyclic U* checkbox to obtain a closed path.
- add an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier to the cube to create the instances along the curve (screenshot 1).

It's important that *All Transformations* for the curve and the cube are applied (<kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode). The cube should be modeled at the world origin (0,0,0). Otherwise, you will get messed-up results.

One disadvantage of this approach is that the *Curve* modifier, unfortunately, deforms the cube instances badly at sharp corners. It is well suited for circles and round corners that Bezier and Nurbs curves have.

[image: curve and array modifier approach]

**2. Another approach is to use the curve with a *Geometry Nodes* modifier that instances the cubes.**

This method won't deform the cubes. But it requires some extra work for the alignment.

- the *Resample Curve* node adds (or removes) new control points and distributes them evenly along the curve. The *Instance on Points* node adds the cubes along the curve.
- the cubes are all aligned in the same direction. If you want to align them along the curve, you need to rotate them. The other four nodes (*Curve Tangent*, *Capture Attribute*, *Align Euler to Vector*, and *Rotate Instances*) do this by aligning the cubes along the tangent of the curve.
- don't forget to apply *All Transformation* as noted above.

[image: curve and geometry nodes]

If you don't like the 45° cornerstones for your castle you need to sort them out with three more nodes (*Vector Math (Dot Product)*, and two *Math* nodes). Also, remove the *Resample Curve* node and add control points manually (subdivide) to the curve path. With <kbd>X</kbd>, *Dissolve Vertice* you can remove control points and make gaps in your wall. The *Resample Curve* node smoothes the curve around the corners even if the spline type is set to poly for some reason. I don't know why. And this messes up the walls.

The *Viewer* node is only used so that you can see the dot product numbers in the spreadsheet.

[image: castle wall example]

Comment: Thank you. I thought about curves but didn't know how to make sharp corners.